# I'm getting the following error: "top-level scope at ./REPL[1]:4" when I run my julia program

Tags: julia

So here's the code I was trying to execute in Julia:

```
i = begin
  i = 5
  while(i<=10)
  println(i)
  i+=1
  end
end
```

It's just basically a simple code to print the value of i from 5 to 10 but it's messing with me

Answer (score 1):

Are you in the REPL? What you are probably running into is that `begin` does not introduce its own scope, so `i = 5` declares `i` as a global variable. Because `while` does introduce its own scope, if you do `println(i)`, it only looks for `i` in its local scope where it is not defined, because `i` exists only as a global variable. You can add a line `global i` at the beginning of the body of the while loop to tell all code after that to use the global `i`, but note that global variables come with their own performance caveats. An arguably better solution would be to use `let` instead of `begin`, which does introduce a new scope, but note that then you can of course not access `i` afterwards, because it is now only local to the `let` block.

This behavior will actually be changed in the upcoming release of Julia 1.5, so your code should then just work.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is [scope](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/). When you enter into a loop, variables created inside the loop are local to the loop and destroyed after it exits. `i` is not currently defined inside your while loop, so you get the error. The quick fix is to tell Julia you want the loop to have access to the global `i` variable you defined at the top by adding `global i` immediately after the while statement. You also don't need the begin block, and naming the block `i` is immediately overwritten by the next statement defining `i`.